# PHP: Form validation in separat file

Tags: php, function, validation

my main page looks like this:

```
<?php
    include "functions.php";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    validate();
    } 
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<input><span><?php echo $deliveryAddressError;?></span>
</form>
```

The functions.php looks like this:

```
function validate()
{
    if (empty($_POST["delivery-address"])) 
    {   
    $deliveryAddressError = "Please input your delivery address.";
    } 

}
```

But when the input is empty the error message does not show up.

Comment: The code is a mess...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/it/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

Function need `return value`

```
function validate()
{
    if (empty($_POST["delivery-address"])) 
    {   
      return $deliveryAddressError = "Please input your delivery address.";
    } else{
      return FALSE;
   }

}
```

You have to assign your return value to your variable

```
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $deliveryAddressError=validate();
        }
```